# Using less4j in Ant to compile less to css

Tags: java, css, ant, less

I am trying to use less4j in Ant to compile LESS to CSS. It seems that less4j should be used in a very simple way(a lot of people recommend it online). But it seems that requires a lot of other jar files. Following is the build.xml I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="compile" default="css.concatenate" basedir=".">
<property name="charset" value="utf-8"/>


<macrodef name="less4j">
                <attribute name="src" />
                <attribute name="css" />
                <sequential>
                        <java jar="${basedir}/lib/less4j-0.0.5.jar" fork="true">
                            <arg value="@{src}" />
                            <arg value="@{css}" />
                                <classpath>
                                    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/less4j-0.0.5.jar" />
                                    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/jcommander.jar" />
                                    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/antlr-runtime.jar" />
                                    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/commons-io.jar" />
                                    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/commons-beanutils.jar" />
                                    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/commons-logging.jar" />
                                </classpath>

                        </java>
                </sequential>
        </macrodef>

<!-- compile LESS -->

<target name="css.concatenate">
    <concat destfile="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/cons/cons.less">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/less">
            <include name="*.less"/>
        </fileset>
    </concat>
    <echo>cons is done!</echo>
</target>



<target name="css" depends="css.concatenate" description="Create CSS">
                <mkdir dir="${basedir}/tryGotCSS" />
                <less4j
                        src="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/less/lessFile.less"
                        css="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/css/trycore.css" />

        </target>


<target name="trasition" >
            <echo> in trasition </echo>

</target>

<!-- precompile handlebars -->

    <!-- -->



</project>
```

However, the errors is like this:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\serverCompiler\build.xml
css.concatenate:
 [echo] cons is done!
trasition:
 [echo]  in trasition 
css.concatenate:
 [echo] cons is done!
css:
 [java] Errors produced by compilation of     C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\serverCompiler/src/main/webapp/less/lessFile.less
 [java] ERROR 13:3 no viable alternative at input 'div' in ruleset (which started at 10:1)
 [java] ERROR 13:9 no viable alternative at input '.' in ruleset (which started at 13:3)
 [java] ERROR 13:23 missing ')' at '0' in abstract mixin or namespace (which started at 13:9)
 [java] ERROR 13:23 missing '{' at '0' in abstract mixin or namespace (which started at 13:9)
 [java] ERROR 13:23 no viable alternative at input '0' in abstract mixin or namespace (which started at 13:9)
 [java] ERROR 13:33 mismatched input ')' expecting '{' in ruleset (which started at 13:23)
 [java] Could not compile the file C:\Users\di_yu\workspace\serverCompiler/src/main/webapp/less/lessFile.less
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is ????? This bug kills me....

Comment: Why posting duplicate questions mate? Both [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688821/how-can-i-run-an-less4j-to-compile-less-to-css-in-ant) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684044/can-i-use-less4j-to-compile-less-into-css-in-ant) seem to be duplicates. If your question is not answered, please be patient and wait till somebody answers it. Creating multiple questions won't help. Please retain only one of the three if all of them are the same problem.

Comment: How I wish you could just give me some advice on the issue...

Comment: I would have done had I known mate. However, be patient there are many people on SO who could help solve it. Now that you have added your error message also to the question you may get better responses.

Comment: You are right, I should be patient.